# Sockets working in the background of android studio

Tags: java, android

I have some problems figuring out how to make a Socket running in the background continuously delivering data to the main thread in Android Studio. For example - the Server reads from different csv files depending on the request send from the socket and send the information back to the socket. I want the Socket to deliver the data back to the main thread without being closed.
The programm below should keep track of the players who are currently connected to the server and the UI Text should be updated correspondingly, but for some reason the UI is updated only once although i can confirm that the function is beeing executed. Would anyone have an advice how should i optimize this so that it works properly. I think that constantly making a new Socket is not the best way to implement it and the threads can't update the UI on time.

```
public class BackgroundTasks {
    private static int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    public static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);

    //stop all threads and release resources
    public void shutdown() {
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    public List<String> getRequest(String id, String typeData){
            Future<List<String>> result = executor.submit(() -> {

                    Socket s = null;
                    try {
                        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
                        System.out.println("Attempting to connect to server..");
                        s = new Socket(Configuration.Server, Configuration.Port);
                        System.out.println(s.isConnected());
                        //reader and writer
                        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

                        out.writeObject(typeData + "," + id);
                        String line = in.readLine();

                        while (line != null) {
                            System.out.println(line);
                            res.add(line);
                            line = in.readLine();
                        }

                        s.close();
                        return res;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("Connection failed!");
                        return null;
                    }
                });

            try {
                return result.get();
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Cant get result");
                return null;
            }
     }

     public void setUserName(String id, String userName) {
         executor.execute(() ->{
             Socket s = null;
             try {
                 List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
                 s = new Socket(Configuration.Server, Configuration.Port);
                 //reader and writer
                 ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

                 out.writeObject(Requests.setUserName + "," + id + "," + userName);

                 s.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         });
     }


     public String getUserName(String id) {
             List<String> result = getRequest(id,Requests.UserName);
             return result.get(0);
     }

}
```

```
public class HostingGameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hosting_game);

    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    AtomicBoolean startGame = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    BackgroundTasks taskExecutor = new BackgroundTasks();
    Button startGame_button = findViewById(R.id.startGame_button);
    startGame_button.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.GRAY));


    updateDataInBackground(startGame,taskExecutor,mAuth);

    startGame_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(startGame.get()){
                    Intent start_game_intent = new Intent(HostingGameActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(start_game_intent);
                    taskExecutor.shutdown();
                }
            }
        });


}
void updateDataInBackground(AtomicBoolean startGame,BackgroundTasks taskExecutor,FirebaseAuth mAuth) {
    BackgroundTasks.executor.execute(()->{
        List<String> host_data_request = taskExecutor.getRequest(mAuth.getUid(), Requests.Host_Data);
        while(!startGame.get()) {

            try {
                startGame.set(updateText(host_data_request));
                host_data_request = taskExecutor.getRequest(mAuth.getUid(), Requests.Host_Data);

            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
boolean updateText(List<String> host_data_request) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
  Future<Boolean> result =  BackgroundTasks.executor.submit(()-> {
      //get views and buttons
        Button startGame_button = findViewById(R.id.startGame_button);
        TextView players_counter_text = findViewById(R.id.player_counter_text);
        TextView players_display_text = findViewById(R.id.players_display_text);
        //extract You text
        String you_text = players_display_text.getText().toString().substring(0,3);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        //count players connected
        int player_counter = 1;

        //clear text and set it new text to the view
        builder.append(you_text + "\n");
        if(host_data_request != null) {
            for (String playerName : host_data_request) {
                player_counter++;
                System.out.println(playerName);
                String[] row_values = playerName.split(" ");
                builder.append(row_values[1]).append("\n");
            }
            players_display_text.setText(builder.toString());
        }

        players_counter_text.setText("Players: " + player_counter);
        if(player_counter > 5) {
            //set Button color if the game can start
            startGame_button.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
  return result.get();
}
```

}

Comment: `to the main thread in Android Studio.` Sockets in Android Studio? And dont you mean the main thread in your Android app?

Comment: `the Server reads from different csv files` Where would the server run? And what about a client? Or clients?

Comment: 1)The surver is just java code executed from another device and the BackgroundTasks class should play the function of an Client as well. The thing is that i am creating a Socket which communicates with the server and after retrieving the data i close the socket instance. If i want to get data again i would have to create a new Socket to connect with the server.

2) Yes i mean the main thread in my android app.
My goal is to run the BackgroundTask in the Background and keep the Socket open and deliver the data continously. But i can't figure out a way without closing the Socket.

Comment: As you see i return a ```List<String>``` containing the data i need. How should i change the code so that i can still return this list but not close the socket and continously deliver this kind of data to my main thread and update the UI. I keep track of that data until some criteria are fulfilled in order to start a game. While the criteria is not fulfilled i need to constantly update the UI (Example: When a player leaves the host activity his nickname should not be displayed anymore)

Comment: While running in a thread you can update the Ui with runOnUiThread().